# Расчёт эластичности в R

Tags: r

Подскажите как найти эластичность фактора по всей выборке? 
А то в пакете `library(margins)` найти как-то не получается.

Answer (score 2):

На аналогичный вопрос уже дали хороший ответ вот тут:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43572657/how-to-calculate-elasticity

Воспроизводимый пример:

```
 # Create a data
 df = data.frame(sales = c(18,20,22,23), Price=c(4.77,4.67,4.75,4.74))

 # Run regression 
 formula = lm(sales~., data=df)

 # Get the summary of the regression 
 summary(formula)

 #Call:
 #lm(formula = sales ~ ., data = df)

 #Residuals:
 #      1       2       3       4 
 #-2.6344 -0.9427  1.3040  2.2731 

 #Coefficients:
 #            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
 #(Intercept)   35.344    170.297   0.208    0.855
 #Price         -3.084     35.983  -0.086    0.940
```

Эластичность спроса по цене, в данном случае, можно рассчитать по формуле:
PE = (ΔQ/ΔP) * (P/Q), где P и Q будут средними по выборке.

```
 The PE = -3.084 * 4.73/20.75 = -0.70

  formula$coefficients["Price"]*mean(df[,2])/mean(df[,1])
  # -0.7033066
```

Эластичность спроса по цене равна -0.7. То есть, при увеличении цены на 1 единицу, при прочих равных, спрос снизится на 0.7.